# Is a belief in djinns shirk?

Tags: shirk, jinn

Salam everyone

A djinn is a being which cannot be seen or heard but can sometimes interact with humans. It is by definition supernatural. Believing in djinns resembles a lot believing in ghosts, witchcraft, pagan deities (spirits of nature, nymphs, ...), or many other superstitions.

Shirk means associating others to Allah. Djinns are associated to Allah by the mere fact that they are supernatural entities.

Hence my question : Is a belief in djinns shirk?

*Following comments : I know djinns are mentionned in the quran. I would like the opinion of someone who does not take the quran to be litterally true*

Comment: Please follow downvotes by an explaining comment, I am open to any critic. In the same way, you can mention if this is off topic.

Comment: Well either you believe in what Allah has told you in the Quran or you'll be a disbeliever! And jinn are definetly quoted in the Quran.

Comment: As a Muslim you have to believe in the unseen. Djinn are a creation of Allah as angles are. So believing that they exsist is part of your belief.

Comment: Do all of you believe the earth is older than the stars, the universe was created in six days, and the moon was split into half (among other things, see http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/do-the-teachings-of-physics-and-astronomy-contradict-the-teachings-of-islam/5385#5385 )? I would be interested by an opinion from people who do not believe the quran litterally.

Comment: @user5751924 "I would be interested by an opinion from people who do not believe the quran litterally." if you mean people who dont believe the Quran is literally the word of god, letter by letter, then youre asking for the opinion of Non-Muslims. other than that, while some verses are considered to be figurative, Islam does teach that Muhammad literally split the moon in two, and the two verses you refer to are understood as being true; at least the 6-days account is understood to not be 6 days consisting of 24 hours each, but rather 6 periods of potentially different length.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shirk_%28Islam%29) definition:

> In Islam, shirk is the sin of practicing idolatry or polytheism, i.e. **the deification or worship of anyone or anything other than the singular God i.e. Allah**. Literally, it means ascribing or the establishment of "partners" placed beside God. It is the vice that is opposed to the virtue of Tawhid (monotheism). Those who practice shirk are termed mushrikun.

Thus:

- Belief in djinn is not shirk, just like belief in angels (or man) is not shirk.  [Belief in angels is one of the [six articles of faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iman_(concept)#The_six_articles_of_faith).]
- Belief that djinn are worthy of worship (in the same way Allah is) amounts to shirk.

From our perspective, djinn are regarded as [supernatural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernatural):

> The supernatural includes all that cannot be explained by science or the laws of nature, including things characteristic of or relating to ghosts, gods, or other supernatural beings, or to things beyond nature.

Indeed, Allah Himself can be regarded as supernatural.  As Muslims, we thus have some supernatural beliefs, while other supernatural beliefs (such as believing in [fortune telling](http://www.islamreligion.com/articles/4064/viewall/fortunetelling)) are prohibited.